# How to work together Bootstrap Dropdown Hover with dropdown-toggle disabled?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu, dropdown

I am using Bootstrap on my website. I am trying to add a link to the dropdown and it is working good on desktop browsers. But not working at the mobil devices. How can I fix them?
Here is my codes:

```
<nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Mobile</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="dropdownlink.html" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">DROPDOWN<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="link1.html">LINK 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.html">LINK 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

And HOVER open Dropdown menu code is:

```
    $(function(){
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

So, when I click the DROPDOWN on mobile, browser is going to the dropdownlink.html and menu is not open. How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
ul.nav li.dropdown.open > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
ul.nav li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
  }
 }
```